# How to get rid of the dollar($) sign in currency field in email template

Tags: email-template, currency

I am thinking of a way to get rid of the $ sign of a currency field in email template. One way to do this is to create a new formula field of number to copy the value which seems a bit clumsy to me. Is there a formula in email template which I can use to get rid of that dollar sign?

Comment: did you try using TEXT or VALUE functions on the merge field ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna TEXT() seems to work for text based email templates but doesn't seem to work for html based ones... Strange.

Comment: have you tried VALUE(TEXT(your field here )) - converting to text then back to a raw number? Not sure if it would work - but worth a shot.

Comment: If a VF email template, you have much more control